# Rails where multiple conditions with nil and not an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

In my Rails issues_controller, I am trying to find articles with an issue that have a department_id of either nil or NOT 1. I am trying the following, and having issues:

```
@articles_other = @issue.articles.where('department_id = ? OR department_id IS NOT ?', nil, 1).order('order_number ASC')
```

Which works locally, but is not showing any return on Heroku - which has confused me more then anything.

Any word on what could be causing such an issue? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a different db locally?

Comment: also, are you sure that the heroku db actually has articles satisfying those conditions?

Comment: I imagine `IS NOT` being Database specific. This does not work in Postgres afaik. Try `<>` instead. That should work in all SQL databases.

Comment: Try rewriting the query as `where('department_id IS NOT NULL OR department_id <> ?', 1)`. In most SQL dialects `IS NOT` is only used with nulls, and `<>` is used with everything else.

Comment: But when a department_id is nil, it is not 1.

Comment: `x = null` doesn't do what you think it does, that comparison should **always** evaluate to NULL unless you're using a non-compliant database.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@articles_other = @issue.articles.where('department_id IS ? OR department_id != ?', nil, 1).order('order_number ASC')
```

Use `'IS'` or `'IS NOT'` when comparing with `'nil'`. Otherwise use normal rails comparators like `<  >  !=`